# trying to popup DisplayAlert when game finish in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am building a game in xamarin in which I am trying to show a DisplayAlert Popup when the game is finished (after 8 seconds). However as the time gets to zero it wont show.
If i put the DisplayAlert at the beginning of the time it works fine.

Can you please explain, why this is the case?

The DisplayAlert line is located in the "OnTimedEvent" Method at the end of the code in this ViewModel:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Timers;
using CBTGAME1.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace CBTGAME1.ViewModels
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class GamePageViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        Animals aninames = new Animals();
        Timer timer;

        private int countSecond;
        public int CountSecond
        {
            get { return countSecond; }
            set
            {
                countSecond = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CountSecond));
            }
        }

        private string nowanimal = null;
        public string Nowanimal
        {
            get { return nowanimal; }
            set { 
                nowanimal = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Nowanimal));
                }
        }


        public Command Generate { get; }
        public Command button1 { get; }
        public Command button2 { get; }
        public Command button3 { get; }

        private int yourscore = 0;
        public int Yourscore
        {
            get { return yourscore; }
            set { yourscore = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Yourscore));
            }
        }

        private string firstb;
        private string secondb;
        private string thirdb;
        public string Firstb
        {
            get { return firstb; }
            set
            {
                firstb = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Firstb));
            }
        }

        public string Secondb
        {
            get { return secondb; }
            set
            {
                secondb = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Secondb));
            }
        }

        public string Thirdb
        {
            get { return thirdb; }
            set
            {
                thirdb = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Thirdb));
            }
        }



        public GamePageViewModel()
        {
            RndAll();
            timer = new Timer();
            settimer();

            button1 = new Command(() =>
            {BtnOperation(firstb); });
            button2 = new Command(() =>
            {BtnOperation(secondb); });
            button3 = new Command(() =>
            {BtnOperation(thirdb); });
        }

        public void BtnOperation(string btname)
        {
            if (btname == Nowanimal)
                Yourscore = Yourscore + 1;
            else Yourscore = Yourscore - 1;
            RndAll();
        }

        public void RndAll()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Nowanimal = aninames.Animalss[rnd.Next(0, 3)];
            int i = rnd.Next(0, 3);

            Firstb = aninames.Animalss[i];
            if (i == 2) i = 0;
            else i++;
            Secondb = aninames.Animalss[i];
            if (i == 2) i = 0;
            else i++;
            Thirdb = aninames.Animalss[i];
        }

        public void settimer()
        {
            CountSecond = 8;
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            timer.Enabled = true;  
        }
        private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            CountSecond--;

            if (CountSecond == 0)
            {
                timer.Stop();
                App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("finished", "have a good day", "Exit");
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `DisplayAlert` returns a `Task`, so `await` it

2) Call it on the main/ui thread

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (async() => {
   await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("finished", "have a good day", "Exit");
});
```